# Kernel Logging disabled?

Tags: linux, iptables, monitoring, logging, syslog

```
uname -a
Linux host 2.6.32-279.9.1.el6.i686 #1 SMP Tue Sep 25 20:26:47 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

And start ups:

```
ls /etc/init.d/
    abrt-ccpp  certmonger  dovecot    irqbalance    matahari-broker             mdmonitor   nfs          proftpd      rpcbind     single     ypbind
    abrtd      cgconfig    functions  kdump         matahari-host               messagebus  nfslock      psacct       rpcgssd     smartd
    abrt-oops  cgred       haldaemon  killall       matahari-network            mysqld      ntpd         qpidd        rpcidmapd   sshd
    acpid      cpuspeed    halt       ktune         matahari-rpc                named       ntpdate      quota_nld    rpcsvcgssd  sssd
    atd        crond       httpd      lfd           ma

tahari-service            netconsole  oddjobd      rdisc        rsyslog     sysstat
auditd     csf         ip6tables  lvm2-lvmetad  matahari-sysconfig          netfs       portreserve  restorecond  sandbox     tuned
autofs     cups        iptables   lvm2-monitor  matahari-sysconfig-console  network     postfix      rngd         saslauthd   udev-post
```

But when I installed CSF/LFD I am getting nothing. LFD does not create lfd.log and nor are any blocks being logged in /var/log/messages either from the firewall. This is not natural.

I looked for klogd but maybe I am looking in the wrong place for it to see if it is enabled?

```
ls /etc/init.d/syslog
ls: cannot access /etc/init.d/syslog: No such file or directory
```

Also noticed no syslog?

Also noticed this:

```
csf -d 84.113.21.201
Adding 84.113.21.201 to csf.deny and iptables DROP...
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

I've never seen this before and this is a dedicated box.

Also:

```
 ./csftest.pl
Testing ip_tables/iptable_filter...OK
Testing ipt_LOG...OK
Testing ipt_multiport/xt_multiport...OK
Testing ipt_REJECT...OK
Testing ipt_state/xt_state...OK
Testing ipt_limit/xt_limit...OK
Testing ipt_recent...OK
Testing xt_connlimit...OK
Testing ipt_owner/xt_owner...OK
Testing iptable_nat/ipt_REDIRECT...OK
Testing iptable_nat/ipt_DNAT...OK

RESULT: csf should function on this server
```

iptables -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: What OS? (cat /etc/issue)

Comment: CentOS release 6.3 (Final)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `/etc/init.d/rsyslog` -- look into `/etc/rsyslog.conf` to see which filters might apply and which destination logfiles are used for kernel messages.